# Get two lookup values 1st is column wise or second is row wise lookup matching then get particular matching results in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I get result like this  (if match the 2 loockup vaues (100 is column  b wise & general is row 8 wise match loockup values)

Results are show like General and Name in second screenshot

Google Sheet Link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h1KSpkN8GYAhavkJyepGTciN9iaHLUv7qo5Zo-qgvn8/edit?usp=sharing

Problems screenshot:

[image]

Get result screenshot:

[image]

Problem is mentioned in screenshot and get the result like this Screenshot

Comment: Please Help try Google Sheet and Provide the Formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `filter()`, like this:

```
=filter(
  CLIENT!C1:J1, 
  C2 = filter(CLIENT!C8:J, B2 = CLIENT!B8:B) 
)
```

Comment: Thank You so much Sir @doubleunary (this formula is working best)